# Error removing nested fields in remote form with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form, cocoon-gem, remote-forms

I have a simple_form with `remote: true`.  I'm adding nested fields to it (people for this example) with cocoon.

```
<%= simple_form_for @incorporation, html: {id:"incorporationform"}, remote: true, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |company| %>
        <div id="people" class="form_section">
            <div class="form-right">
                <div id="dynamic-person" class="dynamic-entity level1 person entityAttributes">
                    <%= company.simple_fields_for :people do |person|%>
                        <%= render 'person_fields', f: person %>
                    <% end %>
                    <div><%= link_to_add_association 'Add Person', company, :people, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This all works very well except under a particular circumstance.  If I'm editing a form that's previously been saved to the database with a few people on it, I cannot perform the following sequence of activities:

1. Remove a person with `link_to_remove_association`
2. Save changes via ajax (remember, `remote: true`)
3. Make ANY other changes
4. Save via ajax again

Everything works until I try to perform that second save, at which point I'm confronted with the following error:

```
19:19:38 web.1  | ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Person with ID=33 for Company with ID=1):
```

The `Person with ID=33` refers to the person I removed in step 1.  When I check the `people` table, in my database.  `Person 33` is indeed gone (indicating that my save in step 2 was good).  My interpretation of what's going on is that after saving the removal, the remote form forgets that `Person 33` is gone and goes looking for him on the next save.

To be absolutely clear, there is no issue if `remote: false` OR if I refresh the page between steps 2 & 3.

Anyone have a guess at a solution for this?  Many thanks in advance to anyone who gives it a shot.

**Edit**
[Upon further research](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/241), it appears that cocoon is really not built to handle ajax submissions.  However [it seems](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/241#issuecomment-62703416) that this can be gotten around by replacing elements in the dom asynchronously.  The comment only provides a summary of the process used.  I'm guessing that they did something like `<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => _person_fields.html.erb)) %>`  However I'm unfamiliar asynchronous rendering of partials.  I imagine that I would have to remove the current partial from the dom and then load a new version of it.  Is this the right idea?  If so, what's the best way to remove the old partial, just straight jquery?